# SSL certificate expired

Tags: tls

Some company was trying to sell me their security system. They said that the SSL certificate was expired on my laptop, which they showed me. They said that I wasn't protected. What are my options?

Comment: did they contact you to tell you that your SSL expired?

Comment: @lostman430 Something is not smelling good. Do you have a website?

Answer (score 6):

As a consumer, you do not need to worry about expired SSL certificates on YOUR machine. SSL certificates are owned by web servers and companies.

If this company contacted YOU to tell you something was wrong with your SSL certificates (and you do not own a web server), I can almost guarantee they are trying to scam you.

Comment: The exception being if he was issued a client certificate for mutual-auth to an application, and that application's management was contacting him to have his client cert renewed, but that is unlikely, and was probably a scam or a social-engineering attempt to cause him to lower his posture in a panic.

Comment: I am going to see if I can get back to the website he took me to .To look at the plans they were selling. I will post my findings as soon as I can.

Comment: @DTK that was my thought, but then they wouldn't be trying to "sell" him something.

Answer (score -1):

You must check sender's email address, if it is from the official source then they could be the real one,

But if the email address seems fake then it could be the phishing scam email. Generally hackers do this kind of stuffs to breach user's data.

Better to stay away and put this email in junk or trash.

Comment: you assume it was an email ...